# libVLC - transcode parameters

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I wrote an streaming server with libVLC. Everything is working perfekt. 
I use this parameters for the streaming

```
#transcode{vcodec=h264}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.255.239,sdp=sap,name=test"
```

But I also want to reduze the filesize of the streamed audio file, let's say to 1/2 of the original file size. 
Is there any way I can solve this with an transcode parameter or with another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the VLC examples includes these example transcode strings:

MP4 High:

```
#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=16},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

MP4 Low:

```
#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=40},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

OGG High:

```
#transcode{vcodec=theo,venc=theora{quality=9},scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

OGG Low:

```
#transcode{vcodec=theo,venc=theora{quality=4},scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

WEBM High

```
#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

WEBM Low

```
#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=1000,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

Changing the various parameters, like reducing bit-rates, will reduce the size of your media.

Comment: Do you know if e.g. `vb=2000` refers to the average bitrate? I am worried about the case when the source has a lower bitrate... in that case, will setting a higher `vb` cause the output to be of (artificially) larger size?

Comment: For reference: https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=doc/libvlc/libvlc_DVD_ripper.c;h=7a6e778991b341218938c85f979c2a8f6bff7669;hb=8d432b090e08f141ce9156dc728afbed4636301b#l105 or https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/3.0.0-git/doc/libvlc/libvlc_DVD_ripper.c#L105-L134